# QRegExpValidator with QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Can QRegExpValidator be used with QTextEdit widget ?

I tried to implement through setValidator() and also set also the qtextedit as parent object. But its not working.

Comment: Do you mean `QLineEdit`? I don't see `setValidator()` method in `QTextEdit` class. As of `QLineEdit`, validator should work fine, need more information to see where the error is.

Comment: I need to use in QTextEdit. I also didn't see setValidator() function. So, I want some examples of the implementation(Can this be used in any other way?).

Answer (score 2):

You should use 

`virtual QValidator::State QRegExpValidator::validate(QString & input, int & pos) const`
 or 
`bool QRegExp::exactMatch(const QString & str) const` 
by yourself. It should not be hard, you just need to determine where to start validate.

Comment: Can you give me some example or link where all these things have already been done ?

Comment: validate() can only be called if can set the validator with qtextedit.

Comment: I can't provide any example, but it should be easy to connect your slot to `textChanged()` signal (or whatever event you want to be a trigger for validation) and call either `QRegExpValidator::validate()` (I'm sure it can be used without setting the validator to QTextEdit), or `QRegExp::exactMatch()`. You will need to provide information of validation status to user by yourself. All of it should be easy to implement

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following things

- define another slot that will be called when textChanged() signal is
  emitted
- emit a signal with two parameters(data in qtextedit and
  length of same data)
- connect the validate() slot with the above slots