# How to sanitize every input for a range of character in my Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, utf-8

I have a Qt application that has a bunch of QLineEdit, QTextEdit etc that the user can modify and put any text he likes.

When saving in this application a XML file is written, partly from what the user has put in these fields. Then the XML file is transformed to HTML through saxonb-xslt.

The problem is that currently the user can enter a range of illegal HTML characters (from 128 to 156 on 1 byte) in these fields, so the XML won't be transformed by saxonb (it rejects it because of illegal HTML characters).

The solution I imagined is creating my own QIODevice overloaded class, and modify the writeData method to transform the data back into a QString, iterate on the QChar and remove every QChar on 1 byte between 128 and 156.

Now this should work in theory, but my question is: I can't be the first one to have this problem, so isn't there a way that can be done easily through a Qt class/method for example? I looked for an already made solution but didn't find it.

Comment: I don't understand the problem at all - the xml writer has to accept all characters and encode it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to best way to handle this is to do input validation already at the input fields. Qt has support for this, see the documentation of the [QValidator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html) class and these SO questions:
[Qt QLineEdit Input Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202697/qt-qlineedit-input-validation)
and (becauese QTextEdit doesn't have support for validators out of the box):
[QRegExpValidator with QTextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446961/qregexpvalidator-with-qtextedit)

Comment: Thanks, that is probably the best way. I edited the validate() function of my QValidator-derived class to modify the string and remove illegal HTML characters.